# Building prediction model using categorical data in R

Tags: r, classification, glm, logistic-regression

Am new to machine learning but, Am trying to build a prediction model, all my training set variables are categorical,

```
PREDICTOR_1     PREDICTOR_2              PREDICTOR_3
 Found        : 5    Best Match   :2        Found, Supplier site: 5   
 No result    : 2    Found        :8        Found, Zone site    : 1   
 Part NotFound:11    Not Found WDA:8        No Data Found       :12   
    PREDICTOR_4                       PREDICTOR_5   PREDICTOR_6
 No result   :11      Found with Different length: 1   High     :10    
 Search begin: 7      No result                  :16   LOW      : 4    
                      Part Found With out Suffix : 1   No result: 4    
     PREDICTOR_7   PREDICTOR_8                PREDICTOR_9       RESULT  
 Direct_Match: 8      NO        :8      Mpn Found within PCN: 3   Found    :15  
 No result   :10      YES       :8      Mpn has no PCN      :15   Not Found: 3  
                      YES-REMOVE:2
```

I tried to use R's glm() function, but I keep getting

```
Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

1- I want to know if it's possible to use only categorical data to train the model
2- What is the meaning of this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 this is possible to use only categorical data in the glm model

2 this error occures when one (or more) explanatory variable has a correlation with response variable equal to 1 or -1.I suggest you should first remove correlated exaplanatory variables (with other explanatory variables) and to remove such explanatory variables that have correlation equal to1 or -1 with response variable. This might be done with `cor` function in R. I suggest  Kendal correlation coefficient for categorical data. Try `cor( data, method = "kendall")`

Comment: am getting this error:  Error in cor(mydatafacotrize, method = "kendall") : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Try:  `cor(as.numeric(mydatafacotrize), method = "kendall")`